# Base64 a PDF Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, express, pdf

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
SaleController.get('/pdf/:contract', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const domainSale = new SaleDomain();
    const result: any = await domainSale.getPdfbyContract(req.params.contract);
    if (result) {
      const pdfBuffer = Buffer.from(result, 'base64');
    
      // Create new PDF document
      const newPdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();
    
      // Add a page with the content from pdfBuffer
      const srcDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBuffer);
      console.log(srcDoc);
      const [newPage] = await newPdfDoc.copyPages(srcDoc, [0]);
      newPdfDoc.addPage(newPage);
      
      // Serialize the new PDF to bytes
      const newPdfBytes = await newPdfDoc.save();
      
      // Send the new PDF as a response
      res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=new.pdf');
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
      console.log(newPdfBytes)
      res.send(newPdfBytes);
    } else {
      throw new Error('PDF not found');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

al momento de general el pdf me sale sin contenido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
al lado izquierdo consumo el api y al lado derecho es lo que me descarga, que es un PDF sin contenido.

me di cuenta de este error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y que te dice la consola? cuando ejecutas el servidor express?

Comment: Nada pero ya encontre el error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Esta es la solución al error:

```
SaleController.get('/pdf/:contract', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const domainSale = new SaleDomain();
    const result = await domainSale.getPdfbyContract(req.params.contract);

    if (result) {
      const pdfBuffer = Buffer.from(result, 'base64');

      // Set the response headers for PDF download
      res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=new.pdf');
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

      // Create a read stream from the PDF buffer
      const pdfStream = new Readable();
      pdfStream.push(pdfBuffer);
      pdfStream.push(null);

      // Pipe the PDF stream to the response
      pdfStream.pipe(res);
    } else {
      throw new Error('PDF not found');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error'); // Envía una respuesta de error al cliente si ocurre un error
  }

});
```